# Node + Express: loadtest causing the application to quit with Error: accept ENFILE

Tags: node.js, express, load-testing

My app quits at relatively low stress point when I run load test on it. For testing I use this npm package [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest).

I run the test at 1000 requests per second with 10 concurrency for 10 seconds.

```
loadtest http://localhost:3000/my/api -t 10 -c 10 --rps 1000
```

The application quits after about two seconds and gives the following error which is not very useful.

```
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: accept ENFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1462:24)
```

Apparently, this is related to the number of open files. I tried this command `ulimit -n <number>` but it doesn't help. It's limited at 9999 (I can't set it above that).

The application can handle around 400rps at 10 concurrencies.

My local machine is a Mac OS Sierra, CPU: 1.6GHz, RAM: 8GB.

Comment: Providing relevant code would be a start because no matter how good (or bad) the machine you run on is, problems in your code can cause any app to crash even with the smallest amount of load.

Comment: How did you conclude the limit to be 9999?

Comment: @peteb the problem is not in the code. It responds to the test at up around 400 rps with 10 concurrencies. I only want to know if somebody could clarify on ENFILE error.

Comment: @robertklep it won't allow me to set at 10000 or above

Comment: @SorakthunLy odd, I run the same OS and I can set it to 20K, 30K, no problem. I tried with `zsh` and `bash` to rule out that it might be a shell-imposed limit.

Comment: @SorakthunLy can you run this command and report what it says? `sysctl kern.maxfiles kern.maxfilesperproc`

Comment: It's 3:40am here and I already turned off my machine. Will do that tomorrow and let you know. Thanks so much for your clarification @robertklep

Comment: @SorakthunLy I think I know the answer already. Feel free to wait for tomorrow morning to read it ;D

Comment: @SorakthunLy According to the [docs for loadtest](https://github.com/alexfernandez/loadtest#usage-donts) you shouldn't attempt to do more than 1000-4000 rps with it because it will overwhelm the single CPU running the test. I don't know if what you're doing qualifies as 10000 rps or 1000. Perhaps wrapping your loadtest in a child process would alleviate the load and distribute it across multiple processes. However your 400rps with 10 concurrecy would hit that 4000 mark described in the docs.

Comment: @peteb it was the limit impose dby macOS that caused the app the crash. thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

macOS sets rather low *kernel* limits on the allowed number of open file descriptors (both in total and per process). I had to check on my wife's Mac, and the default per-process limit is 10240, which is basically spot on to what you are being limited to using `ulimit` ( `ulimit` cannot go beyond the kernel-imposed limit).

It's easy to increase these values, though, running the `sysctl` command:

```
sudo sysctl kern.maxfiles=122880 kern.maxfilesperproc=102400
```

(those are the values that I'm using on my Mac, they are rather arbitrary but work okay for me)

If you want them to stick after a reboot, add the following two lines to the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` (if it doesn't exist yet, just create it):

```
kern.maxfiles=122880
kern.maxfilesperproc=102400
```

Comment: I saw this somewhere too but I wasn't sure what I'd be modifying. This helps a lot. Thanks for being very helpful, mate :D @robertklep

Comment: Do you have an issue of node memory used being accumulated after running the loadtest? What does that tell about your application? Also, what's the max number of request/concurrency can your machine handle in your application? @robertklep

Comment: @SorakthunLy memory being accumulated doesn't necessarily have to be a bad thing as V8 will periodically run a garbage collector to clean that up. Regarding the concurrency, that really depends on what the app does exactly.